# Android - Three Listviews one Fragment; First Listview controls other two; Highlight first Listview choice

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, xamarin

I've gotten three list views showing up on one screen, and I have clicking on an item in the first list view to display the other two list views. The problem is, I can't seem to get the first list view to change it's background to let you know that it was selected.

It works for the other two list views though.

Debugging, I noticed that the first list view's background will have a background color, but once I use that information inside the OnListItemClick listener to populate the other two list views, the highlighting goes away. More specifically, once I assign a new adapter for the other two list views.

My AXML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:text="Unit Converter" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dip">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/QuantityList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
             />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/UnitList1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
            android:listSelector="#FFDAFF7F" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/UnitList2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#FFDAFF7F"
            android:listSelector="#FFDAFF7F" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Interestingly, the text in the first list view stays bold, yet the background color disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for was found at http://www.hambonious.com/2010/06/customizing-android-listview-colors.html.